# Capitalization With Hyphen in Length-Limited Title

Tags: capitalization, headline-case

Imagine a scenario where you had to write the following title:

```
A Scientific Breakthrough
```

However, you were limited in length and had to split it. Do you capitalize “through” even though the original word is not hyphenated? AP and MLA both seem to be missing specific instructions for this. Which of the following is preferable?

```
A Scientific Break-
      through
```

Or

```
A Scientific Break-
      Through
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you're talking about *soft* hyphens, those that only occur when text is wrapped from one line to the next, then it has no bearing at all on the presentation of the word itself—aside from the symbol appearing midway through the word, with the rest of the word continuing on the next line. A soft hyphen is *only* visible in the context of line wrapping, and it is *not* the same thing as a regular hyphen. But are you talking about manually breaking the word? If you would not write *A Scientific Break Through*, it would be odd to use *Break-Through*.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
 A Scientific
 Breakthrough
```

??

Comment: I phrased this as if we were attempting to do this, but in reality, we saw this exact situation on a book cover. The book cover had written it as the second example above, where "Through" was capitalized. I felt as though this was incorrect, as "Breakthrough" is a single word. The book was published recently, so I assume we can rule out an older usage of the word.